# Отправка данных формы сложной модели ASP Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post

Как отправлять форму для сложной модели, для класса ниже. У меня есть форма для создания экземпляра класса. Мне нужно что бы в форме можно было добавлять/удалять редактировать  массив children(класс Child), перед отправкой данных, принадлежащей модели ClientInfoViewModel. Как это можно сделать? Пробовал через js: добавляется только разметка новых членов children, но это не учитывается в модели при отправке формы. Можно конечно через js отправлять изменeния у children, но это придется в контроллере делать статический экземпляр, что не есть хорошо.

```
public class Child
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Имя")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Фамилия")]
        public string? surname { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Отчество")]
        public string? patronymic { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "День рождения")]
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    }
    public class PassportModel
    {
        public Guid? id { get; set; }
        public int? series { get; set; }
        public int? number { get; set; }
        public string? giver { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateIssued { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
    public class ClientInfoViewModel
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Имя")]
        public string? name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Фамилия")]
        public string? surname { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Отчество")]
        public string? patronymic { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "День рождения")]
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }
        public List<Child>? children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
        public PassportModel passport { get; set; }
}
```